# Android Spinner selected Item manipulate

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

My target is to show part of selected spinner item string, as selected item. In Spinner options I want show full string, but when selected only first part of it. Example:

Selected: "Racing Car" > show: "Racing",

Selected: "Fast car" > show: "Fast"

Does that possible? My code:

```
 private void defineRacingCarsArray(){
        racingCarsArray = Arrays.asList(
                "Racing Car",
                "Fast Car"
        );
    }



private void defineRacingCarsCodeSpinner(){
        racingCarsCodeSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.cars_code_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        for (int i = 0; i < racingCarsArray.size(); ++i) {
            adapter.add(racingCarsArray.get(i));
        }
        racingCarsCodeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        racingCarsCodeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String car = racingCarsArray.get(position);
             ;
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: eloborate more what you really want

Comment: When I select item "Racing Car", spinner to show only "Racing" as a selected item.

Comment: spinner to show only "Racing" where you want show it?

Comment: Please read question carefully. I have answer you as well.

Comment: try to get the substring of selected item.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. Although BE wouldn't usually cripple a question that much, it can hardly be understood in its current form. Why don't you just rename "Racing Car" to "Racing" in your code?

Comment: @E_net4 because I want to show in Spinner options "Racing Car", but when I select it, to show only "Racing"

Comment: try like this... **car.replace("car","");**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this,**

```
racingCarsCodeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // here you have to update 
        TextView selectedView = (TextView) view;
        selectedView.setText(racingCarsArray.get(position).split(" ",2)[0]);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: To get 1st word from string in Java

Comment: Please delete this answer. My question is not how to split string. My question is how to show splited string as selected Spinner item.